# OpenCV FileStorage::READ runtime exception

Tags: c++, opencv, try-catch

I am using OpenCV 2.4.6 with VS2012 c++/cli in Windows 8 and trying to simply read a matrix from a file.  At runtime, I am crashing when I try and open the file and I am getting an error saying "System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException" - "External component has thrown an exception".

I have two questions: 1) what is causing this error; and 2) why is try/catch not handling this error?

My code looks like:

```
private: System::Void buttonLoadStyle_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        FileStorage fs;
        try
        {
            fs.open("SVStyle0.xml",FileStorage::READ);
        }
        catch(cv::Exception& e)
        {
            const char * err_msg = e.what();
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Load Style Exception","Rune Time Error!",MessageBoxButtons::OK,MessageBoxIcon::Error);
        }

        if(fs.isOpened())
        {
            // do something
        }
};
```

I get the exception when the the fs.open line tries to open the file.  Further, the exception is not caught by my try/catch blocks.

Comment: Anybody else seeing this?  I also tried renaming the file a "yml" but no luck.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I am having the same issue. Thanks